# How to vertically center a list according to a floatong image by its side?

Tags: list, image, centering

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGkI8.png)

How can I align the list with the center of the image with CSS?

(I am a total beginner, so please explain in simple words)
Thanks !

Comment: You don't want to vertically center this - you want to make it baseline-aligned with the top bullet, otherwise it will look weird when placed next to pairs with fewer bullet-points.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the HTML.